# Element span2 not allowed as child of element div in this context

Tags: html, validation

..says the validator.
What is wrong with this?

```
<div class="theclass"><span>phonenumber</span><br><span2>namename@geemail</span2></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but `<span2>` does not exist in HTML, therefore it would be invalid anywhere, with any validator. You should just use `<span>` again.

I think Bootstrap may have something along the lines of `class="span2"`

Comment: Probably you are right. I don't know where I found this style of using spans. They work anyway. But better put class in it.

Comment: You can use unlimited `<span>` tags and you should. Don't use `<span2>`  as it may not work everywhere the way `<span>` does. If you want to style them relative to their content then I recommend `<span class="phone-number">` and `<span class="email">`

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, could you mark it as correct? So others don't read your question just to realize it has been answered.